# Hadoop EMR using Python

Tags: python, hadoop, emr

I'm using Hadoop streaming to use my mapper and reducer code in python to run a Mapreduce job. I have input data in s3, and I'm trying to use that for the job. However, when I run the command like this -->

```
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*streaming*.jar -file aish1/mapperi.py  
-mapper  aish1/mapperi.py -file aish1/reduceri.py -reducer aish1/reduceri.py 
-file s3://INLOCATION -input s3://INLOCATION -output s3://OUTLOCATION
```

I get the error:

```
File: /home/hadoop/s3:/INLOCATION does not exist, or is not readable. 
Streaming Command  Failed!
```

I don't understand why it adds the /home/hadoop/ in front of my s3 INLOCATION. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `-file` preparation for `input`.
Argument `-file` should be used when you want to use files from local file system, so Hadoop will upload them to HDFS. In you case input is already in appropriable location.

Change you invokation:

`bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*streaming*.jar -file aish1/mapperi.py

-mapper  aish1/mapperi.py -file aish1/reduceri.py -reducer aish1/reduceri.py 
-input s3://INLOCATION -output s3://OUTLOCATION`